# Arguments undefined after passing to React function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameter-passing, react-props

In the Home component we want to call a function:

```
     refreshMatchStatus = (match_id, status) => {
       console.log(match_id)
       var matches = this.state.matches
       matches.map(function(match){
         if (match.id == match_id){
           match.challenged = status
         }
       })
       this.setState({matches: matches})
     }
```

From the Home render this function is passed down to the next component:

```
 <List refreshMatchStatus={this.refreshMatchStatus.bind(this)} showAlert={this.props.showAlert} user={this.state.user} token={this.state.token} matches={this.state.matches}/>
```

The function is then passed down through some components like this:

```
refreshMatchStatus={this.props.refreshMatchStatus}
```

When it arrives in the ChallengePopup component it is executed like this:

```
this.props.refreshMatchStatus(match_id, status)
```

For some reason the arguments `match_id` and `status` are `undefined` when they are passed.

If we do a `console.log` in the ChallengePopup component, one line before the function is called, the `match_id` will return the right id number. But when we do a `console.log` on the first line of the refreshMatchStatus function, the `match_id` returns `undefined`.

We suspect this has something to do with the bind(this), but we cannot find any way to pass the arguments in the right way.

Comment: You should show the component code which contains the `<List refreshMatchStatus={this.refreshMatchStatus.bind(this)} ...>`

Comment: can you post the full code of all relevant components/functions?

Comment: i did encounter same issue in the past , what i did to solve it  is to set a default value in the children component for the props wish surprisingly solved my issue

Comment: have your used arrow function in between while passing this function down

Comment: In fact I believe you don't need the bind at all, since `refreshMatchStatus` is an arrow function, and it will always be called with the context in which it was defined.

Comment: You must have missed an issue in your code anywhere on the way that you did not add here. This is not reproducible. [See the minimal codesandbox example I created](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn8x216o9l).

Comment: Could you please add the full code of the `ChallengePopup` component that calls the handler? The problem doesn't seem to be in the code you provided.

Comment: @RubenSerrate thank you, that solved the problem! If you add it as an answer I can accept it. Still hard to grasp when I have to use bind and arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

Move your bind call to the constructor e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.refreshMatchStatus = this.refreshMatchStatus.bind(this);
}
```

Then you can remove the `.bind` call in your render method, otherwise since its the parent component, every time a fresh render is triggered the method binding is reset which I believe can result in loss of arguments from children.

Comment: Moving the bind to the constructor is a good idea, but I can't see how that'd result in the loss of the parameters

Comment: Well the bottom of his question states "we suspect it might have something to do with the bind" so I offer an alternative method and let them determine for themselves :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, your answer has value, just curious as to why / how it would affect!

Comment: have a look here for explanation https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html